# How to remove rows with "." in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my data:

```
>>> data
            chr      1t        2                 exp        conserve_score       cd         re
1013       chr1     142200     142220          -0.121027      0.0270625         0.0  0.000000
1014       chr1     142220     142240          -0.120995  0.02331578947         0.0  0.000000
1015       chr1     142240     142260          -0.149517  0.03235294118         0.0  0.000000
1308       chr1     169180     169200          -0.182448              .         0.0  0.000000
2046       chr1     439360     439380          -0.112148          0.142         0.0  0.803303
...         ...        ...        ...                ...            ...         ...       ...
150209142  chr5  180756500  180756520           0.145244        0.28205         0.0  0.968969
150209143  chr5  180756520  180756540           0.164834         0.3497         0.0  0.968969
150209144  chr5  180756540  180756560           0.160763   0.3825555556         0.0  0.968969
150209145  chr5  180756560  180756580           0.160709   0.3932857143         0.0  0.968969
150209146  chr5  180756580  180756600           0.160709   0.3829444444         0.0  0.968969
```

some rows has values . and I want to remove those rows

I tried

```
>>> data[data.conserve_score.str.contains(".")==False]
Empty DataFrame
Index: []
```

but in float numbers, there are also "." ...
How to make it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with `all`:

```
data = data[data.ne('.').all(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to drop rows where the column `conserve_score` has value `"."`, you can simply subset your dataframe to include rows that are not equal to `"."`.

```
data = data.loc[data["conserve_score"] != "."].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `.` with `np.nan` and then use `dropna`:

```
df = df.replace('.', np.nan).dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code with

```
data[~data.conserve_score.astype(str).str.contains(".")]
```